# How can I add hover effect on react-router custom link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router custom link for to highlight the active path/link in in navbar and everything working well. But I cant add hover effect on those link. I used `.nav-link a:hover` and try to add some styles but it doesn't work.

```
    const CustomLink = ({ children, to, ...props }) => {
        let resolved = useResolvedPath(to);
        let match = useMatch({ path: resolved.pathname, end: true });
    
        return (
            <div className="nav-link">
                <Link
                    style={{
                        textDecoration: match ? "underline" : "none",
                        color: match ? "#FDC300" : "white",
                        fontWeight: match ? 500 : 400
                    }}
                    to={to}
                    {...props}
                >
                    {children}
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default CustomLink;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not style them through the `style` property, as that has higher specificity than any css rule (*unless you resort to `!important`*).

Just add a class to signify that it is active.

```js
    const CustomLink = ({ children, to, ...props }) => {
        let resolved = useResolvedPath(to);
        let match = useMatch({ path: resolved.pathname, end: true });
        const linkClassNames = match ? 'active' : '';
        return (
            <div className=`nav-link ${linkClassNames}`>
                <Link
                    to={to}
                    {...props}
                >
                    {children}
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default CustomLink;
```

```css
.nav-link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-link.active a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #FDC300;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

---

You could however use the [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink) component (*provided by the react router*) which supports this

```
<NavLink
  to="wherever you want"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link'
  }
>
   your link text here
</NavLink>
```